# access denied in browser (IE8) when I try to retrive xml file

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

I have the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

And then the file continues with other stuff... The problem is that I get an error on the line with xmlhttp.open which says Access Denied in IE 8.
I run all this files locally and all of them are in the same folder... what can I do to get rid of this error? I googled it a little bit and it seems that the error remains. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure everything is the same? try to use a full address like: `http://www.mydomain.com/path/test.xml`, make sure that the protocol (http/https), the port (80/8080...) and the domain are the same (subdomains are not considered the same domain!)

Comment: I had the same issue, but i just used a local webserver to sort it out, this post http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/issues/detail?id=23 details the issue too and suggests that if you use the ActiveX in preference the native xhr on IE then it will work but give security warnings

Comment: So pretty much I have no options?

Comment: I would like it to work out of the box without having the user making and changes in his IE Settings...

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure but most probably the issue may be because of the cross domain. I.e xmlparsing needs the xml and corresponding files to be uploaded in somje local server. Try using [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-55.cgi) or [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper) and call from the server using "http://localhost/appname". hope it works