# xml alternative for javascript app used on IE?

Tags: javascript, xml, excel, internet-explorer

What would be the best alternative to xml for a javascript app. The app parse the data then uses Highcharts framework to show some charts.
I can't use xml because it has problems running locally on Internet Explorer (access denied error and other problems ....[see my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555674/access-denied-in-browser-ie8-when-i-try-to-retrive-xml-file)).
Also this new thing that should replace xml in this situation should be exported from excel.
I was thinking about csv... but csv can be a little bit messy an not as easy to use as xml.
Thanks!

Comment: The problem you mention in your other question is caused by the "HTTPRequest" part, not the "XML" part. XML is a suitable choice for the data format.

Comment: I understand but maybe other technology works without HTTPRequest? Or maybe there is any way to getit work without that error in IE...the problem is that I'll use this stuff at work and there everybody uses IE and if some error will appear they won't know what to do...also it has to work out of the box because they aren't allowed to change IE's security options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best data format that you can use with JavaScript is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) - it was designed for it.

Comment: thanks... does it work without http request? I started to read right now about JSON...

Comment: Well it does "work without httprequest" (e.g `var a = {"test" : "yeah"};`) but I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that

Comment: JSON and JSONP are the way to go if you want a light weight data format and no cross domain issues. The explanation on wikipedia is pretty straightforward: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP